# Facebook OpenGraph Not Working

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I've updated the page http://www.techcentral.ie/article.aspx?id=17031 to include the required meta tags but they don't seem to be picked up by http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint?url=http%3A%2F%2F

I thought I had included everything that is required.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="ICANN votes for huge domain expansion as users shrug"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article" /><meta property="og:url" content="http://www.techcentral.ie/article.aspx?id=17031"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.techcentral.ie/img/thumbnail/corporate/web_presence_10.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="TechCentral.ie" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="236362129712825" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Is it all too late to matter?">
```

I also added xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" in the DOCTYPE declaration

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you have any luck figuring this out? Similar problem.

Comment: Having the same issue, it can't find the image for some reason. Let me know if you find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the "og:type" meta tag as content="[app_name]:[object]"